# How to get MSBuild to print command output in post-build task?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2005

I have a Visual Studio 2005 solution/vcproj which has a post-build task that runs unit tests. I want to build it using msbuild.exe.

However, when the tests fail, I do not see any output logged to the console (I've verified that output is logged when executed at the command line.) I can see the output if I use the /v:detailed parameter. Is there a better way to do this? Ideally, I only want to see the output if a test fails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the best way I've found is to call msbuild and pass parameters down to vcbuild:

```
msbuild ... /p:VCBuildAdditionalOptions="/M /logfile:logfile.log" || type logfile.log
```

So if the build fails, the errors that were logged will be output at the end of the build which is sufficient for me.